# Symfony 1.4 sfWebResponse modify content before sendContent

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have extended the standard symfony sfWebResponse and I would like to modify the html in the response.

The only way I have managed to get this to work is by replicating the standard sendContent function and modifying the html in $content before it is echoed.

Am I going about this the wrong way? (I have a feeling I am).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can listen response.filter_content event :
http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/15-Events#chapter_15_sub_response_filter_content

Like here : https://github.com/vjousse/symfony-1.4/blob/master/lib/log/sfWebDebugLogger.class.php#L49

Comment: I actually used something similar to what is found in the sfResponse class. `$event = $this->dispatcher->filter(new sfEvent($this, 'response.filter_content'), $this->getContent());`

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter, move it right before the Output (order in filter.yml) and use the sfWebResponse to get and set the Content.

```
class makestuff extends sfFilter {

    public function execute(sfFilterChain $filterChain) {
        $filterChain->execute();
        $response = $this->getContext()->getResponse();
        $response->setContent(  $response->getContent()." this comes after </html>" );
    }
}
```